# What is an "artificial decompression"?

Tags: emergency

Have anyone heard about "artificial decompression" ? And if yes, what does that mean ?
I know decompressions are usually classified as "explosive", "rapid" and "gradual" or "slow", but I've never heard about "artificial decompression" until a friend asked me about it...
Thanks !

Comment: Is there any example of the term being used besides your friend asking about it? May not be a real thing, or may be used in some very limited, niche context. Without some example of the term being used, it may be hard to answer this question very well.

Comment: Don't know for sure. I would interpret it as a decompression initiated on purpose, by pumping air out, for training or testing, as in an altitude chamber, where air will be sucked out slowly for hypoxia training, or quickly for explosive decompression training.

Comment: What’s the context/source?

Comment: Ralph, John, and Tedder: thanks for your comments... I'm currently trying to gather more informations/context about this "procedure"... I will keep you posted ! Thanks

Answer (score 4):

It turned out that the term "artificial decompression" was a one-off encountered in a general article mentioning a case where the PIC decided to intentionally induce a decompression (using the cockpit system controls) with the intent to surprise and subsequently subdue some hijackers ( it is unknown if this is fictional...).
After additional research, I couldn't find any other usage of the term.
Thank You very much for your on point help (Ralph, John & Tedder) !

Comment: I might quibble with the original author & suggest that this is more the case of an ***intentional*** depressurization that "artificial," but that's a tiny point. Thanks for the update on the source of the term in question!